Where can I find Asarah Ma'amarot in English online?
I'm looking for the English translation of Asarah Ma'amarot by Rabbi Menachem Azaria de Fano, specifically Ma’amar Chikur Din 3:21.
It can be a community translation of that specific Ma'amar, or a link to an online source. Thanks!

I'm not sure it's ever been translated. Are you perhaps aware of any printed translation?

Why is this tagged noachide laws?

I found the Hebrew text here
and translated the first part using ChatGPT as below. Please evaluate and if useful continue the translation yourself using ChatGPT (https://chat.openai.com/).

"Jacob shall not be ashamed now when he sees his children exiled to
Egypt, which is constricting to the Land of Israel, for the Divine
Presence descended with them to cause a rose to bloom among the
thorns, which is the tribe of Solomon, and to gather to itself the
scattered of Israel—these being the sparks of holiness that remained
with the snake until then. And through the iron furnace, those who had
joined the House of Jacob in earlier times, who were gathered together
but not yet at the right time, were brought back and judged in a
similar manner. First by the decree of the Nile and the dispersal to
make bricks, as we will mention further. However, during the Flood and
the Dispersion, their embers were extinguished without repentance. But
here, Pharaoh offered them up to their Father in Heaven. And those who
were there and were not worthy of redemption died through repentance
and crying out, which are effective even to the point of utter
soul-crushing. Likewise, during the days of darkness, many of the
sinners died, but it is written, 'For all the children of Israel,
there was light in their dwellings.' And the abundance here indicates
that even those unworthy of redemption, since they died through
repentance as we said, had light in their dwellings in the Garden of
Eden, and none were missing. Or it can be interpreted that in their
dwellings, those worthy of settling and being redeemed had light, and
these are the six hundred thousand that God brought close to Mount
Sinai. Then, He saw and waived for everyone else the seven general
commandments, and specified thirty, as it is stated in the chapter of
Gid HaNasheh (the prohibition of eating the sciatic nerve), and these
are they:"
(Note: The translation maintains the interpretive and allegorical
nature of the original text, which may refer to Kabbalistic or
Midrashic traditions.)

The next part is translated by ChatGPT as follows:

"First, idolatry and associated practices: passing children through
fire, sorcery, divination, magic, enchanting, consulting mediums,
necromancy, and seeking the dead. According to Rabbi Yose, who said
that all those mentioned in the portion about sorcery are prohibited
to the descendants of Noah. Thus, there are ten commandments.
Second, forbidden sexual relations, and associated with it: being
fruitful once and multiplying twice as a positive commandment, the
prohibition of sodomy even if they make a formal marriage contract,
the prohibition of hybrid animals, castration, and grafting
trees—these are seven, as explained further.
Third, murder, and striking the face of an Israelite is associated
with it, so there are two.
Fourth, blasphemy, and respect for the Torah is associated with it, as
well as the obligation to engage in the Torah given to them (the
Noahides), because a Noahide who engages in it is like a High
Priest—thus, there are three.
Fifth, theft, and not engaging in Torah that is our inheritance is
associated with it, so there are two.
Sixth, the establishment of courts for the settlement of the world,
and not allowing them to cease is associated with it, so there are
two.
Seventh, the prohibition of eating a limb from a living animal, and
associated with it: the prohibition of blood from a living animal,
carcasses, and the flesh of the dead—thus, there are four.
In total, there are thirty. Even though 'be fruitful and multiply' is
one commandment for us, and among the 613 commandments, it might seem
difficult to understand why it is divided into two here. This is
because we do not derive the law for the descendants of Noah from the
Torah of Moses our teacher. Alternatively, 'be fruitful and multiply'
is always counted as one for both us and them. The commandment of
establishing courts is divided into two, one as a positive commandment
and one as a negative commandment, as is explained in the Talmud.
Rashi explained it as follows: one is to judge fairly, and the other
is to avoid injustice.
The sacrifices for the early generations were like one who is not
commanded but does them regardless. This seems to me to support all
the words of the sages. All of these were repeated in the chapter on
the four modes of execution, except for three, which are found in the
chapter on the sciatic nerve. This matter is in accordance with all
the Tannaim and Amoraim, where one sage said one thing, and another
said another, but they do not disagree."
And these three that we mentioned refer to the prohibitions against
sodomy, human flesh, and the respect for the Torah. There is also the
prohibition against the meat of a carcass, which is clearly taught in
the Pesikta from the verse: 'Every creature that is alive' (Genesis
9:3), excluding a carcass, meaning an animal that died of itself. This
is not in accordance with the words of Tosafot in the chapter 'Four
Modes of Execution,' where they said that in such a case, it was
permitted to the first human (Adam) based on the verse 'You may surely
eat' (Genesis 2:16), and not 'limb from a living animal,' which
everyone agrees was not permitted. However, it was not allowed to kill
an animal, wild beast, or bird for the sake of eating meat. It is
implied that it was permitted to kill for medical purposes or to
benefit from their hides, and later, eating their meat was also
permitted.
As for the statement about 'seeing and permitting,' do not infer from
this that it would be allowed for us to cause another person to sin.
For it was taught explicitly: a person should not hand a limb from a
living animal to a Noahide, and the Torah specifically stated, 'You
shall throw it to the dog' (Exodus 22:30). Rather, it was permitted to
them (the Noahides), but they will eventually be held accountable as
those who have sinned repeatedly. This is discussed in chapter 14.
Alternatively, it was permitted to them, but even if they fulfill
those commandments, they do not receive reward like those who are
commanded to do so, but rather like those who perform a commandment
voluntarily, for there are no longer rejected souls for whom it was
originally thought that they should not be left without Torah even for
a single moment."


Thank you, I was actually looking for the next part that starts with: "ראשונה עבודת אלילים ונטפלות אליה מעביר באש קוסם מעונן מנחש ומכשף חובר חבר אוב ידעוני דורש אל המתים. כרבי יוסי דאמר כל האמור בפרשת מכשף בן נח מוזהר עליו. הרי עשר מצות. שנית גלוי עריות ונטפלות אליה פרו אחת ורבו שתים במצות עשה ואסור הזכור אפילו יחדו בכתובה וכלאי בהמה והסרוס והרכבת אילן הרי שבע עיין בסמוך. שלישית שפיכות דמים וסוטר לועו של ישראל טפלה אליה הרי שתים...."
(hence why this is tagged under noachide laws - to answer that question too).

Second part added to answer above.
